# Вычисление факториала

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите по коду что можно еще дописать или переделать?
программу, вычисляющая факториал
натурального числа n, которое пользователь введёт с клавиатуры.

Как еще можно убрать 1, если например я делаю ввод отрицательного числа там мне выдает "Вы ввели отрицательный факториал!", а над ним выдает  1?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       int n;
        do {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.print("Введите факториал натурально числа n : ");
              n = scan.nextInt();
               int result = 1;
                for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
                  result *= i;
                  System.out.println(result);
                if (n == 0 || n == 1)
                 System.out.println(result);
             if(n < 0)
             System.out.println("Вы ввели отрицательный факториал!");
        } while (n < 0);{System.out.println("Конец");}
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуй почитай про рекурсию =)и посмотри как просто и правильно писать факториал, а не занимайся велосипедоизобретательством 

Comment: А нафига??? В данном случае рекурсия и памяти жрет больше и скорость работы у нее поменьше будет. Не говоря уже о том, что StackOverflow наблюдаться может при ее использовании.

 private static long factor1(long p) {
  return (p == 1 ? 1 : p * factor1(p - 1));
 }
 
 private static long factor2(long p) {
  long res = 1;
  for(; p>0; p--) res *= p;
  return res;
 }

А то, что у turtles сам код никуда не годится, cy6erGn0m уже сказал.

Comment: "как ... правильно писать факториал" наверно, одна из самых распространенных ошибок в книгах по программированию - это демонстрировать работу рекурсии на примере вычисления факториала, где рекурсия вообще не нужна (ну т.е. если язык позволяет писать циклы).

Comment: так судить можно про все что хочешь и с такими аргументами рекурсия вообще не где не нужна, а это всего небольшой пример рекурсии, где аргументы про "больше памяти и скорость работы" вообще не катируются, имхо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так вы сначала проверку на отрицательный ввод сделайте, а потом уже факториал считайте в остальных случаях. Ну же, подумайте же. Перестаньте заниматься компиляцией. Это не имеет ничего общего с написанием рефератов ;)

И зачем System.out.println("Конец"); вы засунули в фигурные скобки ?

И почему условие в do .. while такое странное?

И почему в случае 0 и 1 вы печатаете результат дважды ?

Comment: Спасибо за очень хороший совет, нашел ответ на свой вопрос!

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, можно я изменю ваш ответ, добавив в него полный пример кода?

Answer (score 3):

```
    int y=1;
    int n=8;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        y=y*i;
    }
    System.out.print(n+"!=");
    System.out.print(y);
```